# document.querySelectorAll on typescript: Type 'NodeListOf<HTMLElement>' is not an array type.ts(2461)

Tags: typescript, dom

I've been trying a way to get the following on typescript:

```js
    [...document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>("#node-a input, #node-a button")].forEach(item => {
//code
    })
```

But I get the following error:

`Type 'NodeListOf<HTMLElement>' is not an array type.ts(2461)`

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array. To treat it as an array you can use `Array.from()` as suggested, or change your code to expect a NodeList instead. Note that some browsers don't support using `forEach()` with NodeLists.